# Prime Factor Problem To Solve

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For any positive integer $n>10$, $\lfloor \sqrt{n!}\rfloor$ has always a prime factor $> n$.

Comment: The claim is directly verified for $n=10$ and $n=9$, so why does the problem not state "for any $n>8$"?

Comment: I only need the result proved for n>10.

Comment: Where have you encountered this problem? It seems like you might be doing something really interesting, and if you're able to share I think we'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'm trying some ideas on Legendre's conjecture, that there is a prime number between n² and (n + 1)² for every positive integer n.

Comment: Off-topic !!! That's weird, just because I said Legendre's conjecture :)

Comment: I think this question is clear and interesting, maybe it belongs to open problems.

Comment: Upto $n=10^4$, the claim is true. A counter-example would be a $n$-smooth number. As the given number growths exponentially with $n$, the probability that the number is $n$-smooth will rapidly decrease, so the claim is almost surely true. A proof of the claim is probably out of reach.